# Ignoring whitespaces in records in elastic search using aggregation functions

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field name in elasticsearch as "smartaccountname". It contains whitespaces. While doing aggregation functions like terms, cardinality it is not taking the whole string as single string. It splits the string as two.
For example, 
**cardinality**:

```
"aggregations": {
"1": {
"value": 2
}
```

It should be 1.

**terms**

```
    "aggregations": {
"1": {
"doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
"sum_other_doc_count": 0,
"buckets": [
{
"key": "FIRE",
"doc_count": 2
}
,
{
"key": "DEVICES",
"doc_count": 2
}
]
}
}
```

It should be FIRE DEVICES : 2

**Field structure**

```
 **smartaccountname**
    FIRE DEVICES
    FIRE DEVICES
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the mapping of that field, you need to change it and add a sub-field to it, or use the already existent sub-field on it.

Basically, your mapping for that field should be similar to this:

```
      "smartaccountname": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
```

Then, in your aggregation you should use the `smartaccountname.keyword` field:

```
        "cardinality" : {
            "field" : "smartaccountname.keyword"
        }
```